# Why is the web page zooming in after rotating a mobile device from landscape to portrait?

Tags: html, mobile, viewport, device-orientation

I have a webpage optimized for viewing in a mobile.

I am utilizing the `viewport` meta tag `<meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width">` which detects the device width and sets the viewport width to that. This means my webpages load properly in a mobile browser rather than looking ridiculously zoomed out.

When I load the page on my mobile (which is a Samsung Galaxy S2) in portrait mode it looks fine, I rotate to landscape and it looks fine, **but then if I rotate back to portrait again the page has zoomed in slightly**. I either have to zoom out or scroll horizontally.

**Why is my mobile browser doing this and how can I stop it happening?**

See screenshot for a visual aid to what is happening.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, this is happening for me too

Answer (score 0):

It seems that even though a resizeEvent is firing after orientation change, the device is still failing to reset the zoom after zooming in to fill the wider landscape viewport.

I had to do BOTH of the following to get the display to resize properly after orientation change:

(1) Setting minimum-scale=1.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, 
minimum-scale=1.0">
```

(2) In CSS file:

```
body {
 height: 100vh; 
 height: -webkit-fill-available; 
 min-height: 100vh; /* Fallback for browsers that do not support Custom Properties */
 min-height: -webkit-fill-available; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what you need

```
<meta content='width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;' name='viewport' />


<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Comment: could you elaborate as to what this will do please? From looking at it, it seems as though that will prevent the user from manually zooming in/out.

Comment: do you need both? this answer confuses me even though i'm familiar with the viewport meta tag. I was seeing this on iOS and used the second line here to get a decent solution, but it's still an issue on android for me.